# How to access an element's ref index within the nested v-for loop in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to access an element within the nested v-for loop by using the refs index of the element? I mean, I'm trying to focus a textbox that is within the nested v-for loop which I used to access by its refs index. It works fine for a single v-for loop but not with nested.

For more details here's my loop structure:

**This works**

```
<div v-for="(comItem, index) in commentItems" :key="comItem.commentId">
 <textarea ref="addRep" ></textarea>
</div>
  this.$nextTick(() => {
                        this.$refs.addRep[index].focus()
                    });
```

**This won't work**

```
<div v-for="(cont, i) in contentItems" :key="cont.contentId">
    ...
     <div v-for="(comItem, index) in commentItems" :key="comItem.commentId">
     <textarea ref="addRep" ></textarea>
     </div>

</div>
  this.$nextTick(() => {
                        this.$refs.addRep[index].focus()
                    });
Or
 this.$nextTick(() => {
                        this.$refs.addRep[i].focus()
                    });
```

With the nested html v-for loop structure. The focus will just jump around anywhere. To anyone who encountered this kind of scenario. Please assist me if you know the solutions. Thanks.

Comment: When you say it *'won't work'*, could you be more specific? What does happen? Within the `$nextTick` callback where are you getting the values for `index` and `i`? Have you tried logging the value of `this.$refs.addRep` within that callback to see whether the array exists and what is in it? Is the problem simply trying to calculate the appropriate array index within a nested loop?

Comment: I did all the loggings for getting the values of each indexes. What happens is if it's in the nested html structure with v-for loops the focus is not consistent anymore. It will just jump around anywhere.

Comment: @skirtle I think the problem is simply trying to calculate the appropriate array index within a nested loop.

Comment: 1. Should `:key="contItem.commentId"` be `:key="comItem.commentId"`? I don't see `contItem` defined anywhere. 2. Is there a link between the outer and inner loop? As presented in the question the inner loop is just churning out the same list of `commentItems` for each `cont` item. I would expect it to be something like `v-for="(comItem, index) in cont.commentItems"`. I know this sounds like an unimportant detail but it makes a huge difference to how to calculate the appropriate index.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo error it was <div v-for="(comItem, index) in commentItems" :key="comItem.commentId">

Comment: I think the issue here is how to get the specific index for parent and child.

Comment: To put my second question another way, what is the link between `contentItems` and `commentItems`? The code in the question implies they are entirely independent of each other, so the list of comments will be the same for all the content items. This seems unlikely to be true but it does massively simplify the index calculations if it is true.

Comment: contentItems and commentItems are two different arrays. Simply contentItems is the parent and commentItems is the child array if you look at the html structure above. Here's the methods I used  
From here within the nested loop <a class="reply" @click="RepComment(index)" tabindex="0">Reply</a>
then on the methods:
RepComment(foc) {
                    
                    this.$nextTick(() => {
                        this.$refs.addRep[foc].focus(),
                          
                    });                 
                },

Comment: Both arrays have different results but the every parent array(contentItems ) have a specific commentItems results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to calculate the appropriate index within `addRep` is a little tricky. You'd need the values of both `i` and `index` and then count up through the relevant arrays to work out the appropriate index.

A simpler way to do this is to use a dynamic `ref` name. We still need `i` and `index` to find the relevant element but there's no calculation required.

The core trick here is to set the ref to `` :ref="`addRep${i}`" ``, or equivalently `:ref="'addRep' + i"` if you prefer. So you'll end up with multiple named refs, `addRep0`, `addRep1`, etc., each with its own array of elements. The value of `i` tells you the ref name and the `index` tells you the index within that array.

Here's an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data () {
    return {
      contentItems: [
        {
          contentId: 1,
          comments: [
            {
              commentId: 1,
              text: 'A'
            }, {
              commentId: 2,
              text: 'B'
            }, {
              commentId: 3,
              text: 'C'
            }
          ]
        }, {
          contentId: 2,
          comments: [
            {
              commentId: 1,
              text: 'D'
            }
          ]
        }, {
          contentId: 3,
          comments: [
            {
              commentId: 1,
              text: 'E'
            }, {
              commentId: 2,
              text: 'F'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    onButtonClick (i, index) {
      this.$refs[`addRep${i}`][index].focus()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(cont, i) in contentItems" :key="cont.contentId">
    <h4>{{ cont.contentId }}</h4>
    <div v-for="(comItem, index) in cont.comments" :key="comItem.commentId">
      <textarea :ref="`addRep${i}`" v-model="comItem.text"></textarea>
      <button @click="onButtonClick(i, index)">Focus</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```